# How to automate SSRS reports using python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am working on a project where I need to generate almost 40 reports every month from SSRS reporting services. I have been trying to automate it using python but I am missing something in the URL that I am passing. Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to show some code otherwise everyone will be guessing as to what you're missing.

Comment: session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username= '<>' , password= '<>')
filename = 'C:\SSRS Reports\\report.pdf'
username = "<>" password = "<>"
url = "http://<>/reportserver?/report/<params>&ReportMonth=08&ReportYear=2020"
r = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('<>','<>' ))
print(r.status_code) if r.status_code == 200: with open(filename, 'wb') as out: for bits in r.iter_content():
out.write(bits)

Answer (score 1):

Your URL should consist of the following:

`http://`
`<reportservername>`/
`ReportServer?`/
`<nameofreport>`
`?<param1>=<value1>&<param2>=<value2>`
`&rs:Format=PDF`

You'd have to replace all '<...>' placeholders with your server and report information.

Here's an example: `https://servername/reportserver?/SampleReports/Employee Sales Summary&EmployeeID=38&rs:Format=PDF`

This sample URL simply tells SSRS to get the `Employee Sales Summary` report in folder `/SampleReports` passing the parameter `EmployeeID=38` and render the report as a PDF file.

Comment: session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username= '<>' , password= '<>')
 
filename = 'C:\SSRS Reports\\report.pdf'

username = "<>"

password = "<>"

url = "http://<>/reportserver?/report/<params>&ReportMonth=08&ReportYear=2020"

r = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('<>','<>' ))

print(r.status_code)

if r.status_code == 200:

    with open(filename, 'wb') as out:

        for bits in r.iter_content():

            out.write(bits)

--I am able to get 200 from the server. Able to write the file but when I try to open the pdf file I get this..

Comment: --I am able to get 200 from the server. Able to write the file but when I try to open the pdf file I get this.."Adobe cannot open the  report.pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged."

Comment: @Sia check your pdf file size. It may be zero bytes.

Comment: Just 1 kb. Guess it is not writing anything.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Copy the URL and paste it into a browser. Are you getting a pdf back and if so does the pdf open without errors?